# Present a Google document and an audio file at the same time in Google Meet

Tags: google-docs, google-meet

I'm a teacher. How can I present a Google document and an audio file at the same time in Google Meet so my students can listen to the audio file and answer the questions presented on the Google document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google docs does not support audio files, so one option would be to move the question to a Google Slides presentation, which does allow audio files.

Another option would be to share your whole screen with two windows open. One with the audio file, one with the Google doc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! The second option doesn't seem to work as the audio file is mute for my students. This is what I get: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXFWo.jpg).

Comment: I see. Looks like a limitation of Google Meet. I would give the first option a shot if you haven't already.